# Write while multiple readers are reading from different threads in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, race-condition

I know I can use RwLock to wait for reading threads to finish reading, although I was wondering if it was possible to write data while the readers were reading non-atomically (I don't really care whether readers get an old copy of the data or a new one, as long as the memory gets updated)
Is this possible in safe (or unsafe rust)?

A little more about my specific problem: I have an object that may take a long time to write to but I want to have readers reading from it constantly.

EDIT: More specifically, I have a Cache that holds different objects. These objects simply hold a byte (u8) array. This byte array needs to be read from different threads as well as being written to (the writing parses a large cumbersome struct and converts various fields into the byte array).

Comment: If it takes a "long time" to write the object, how would you prevent readers from getting a partially-updated copy?

Comment: In my code, it doesn't matter whether readers get a partially updated object, the readers only need some state of the object, not the latest state. The object is also statically sized and doesn't point to any external memory, so there won't be any conflicts from data being written differently between each run of the write function.

Comment: Are you sure the state will always be *consistent* in the middle of these long writes? Perhaps you could give some more detail about what exactly you're doing.

Comment: I'm sure it is consistent, added more detail above ^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use-case of the [`arc-swap`](https://docs.rs/arc-swap) crate, which allows you to atomically swap one [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) for another. Every time you wish to create a new version of your data, you create a clone of the data and put the new version in an `Arc`, swapping out the old `Arc`. Code that needs to read can get a clone to the `Arc` currently in the `ArcSwap`, and the old version is destroyed once there are no more handles to the old version.

If you need to modify the data from multiple places, you should employ the following pattern using a `Mutex`.

1. You have an extra version used for updates stored inside the `Mutex`.
2. When you wish to update the data, lock the mutex and make your changes.
3. Make a clone of the object stored in the `Mutex` and put it into the `ArcSwap`.
4. Then unlock the mutex.

Any code that wishes to read the data will take a clone from the `ArcSwap` and never touch the `Mutex`. It is important that the mutex is unlocked after swapping the `Arc` with the new version.

Comment: Wow, what are the odds! you answered my other question about `AsyncRead`ers on the rust user forum. I will be sure to `cargo add arc-swap` to using in my caching system.